# facebook api - losing my scope

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm developing application using facebook API.
what i'm trying is simple - get a post, and then get the number of likes this post has.

then i want to combine the post story and its number of likes.
later i will want to do it with a loop - iterating over a series of posts.

my problem explanation is inside the code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#mybutton").click(function () {
        FB.api("/me/posts", function (response) {
            /* first callback
             *
             * i have access to global scope here.
             */

            var firstpost = response.data[0];

            FB.api("/" + firstpost.id + "/likes", function (response) {
                /* second callback inside the first callback
                 *
                 * here i lost my access to the first callback scope.
                 * my access is only to local and global scope. 
                 * i can't see anymore what is inside firstpost variable;
                 */
                console.log(firstpost);
                //this will give a reference error
            })
        })
    })
});
```

perhaps there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use different names for the response parameter, but there is a much better way by just using one API call:

```
/me/posts?fields=message,likes
```

...or with the JS SDK:

```
FB.api('/me/posts', {fields: 'message,likes'}, function (response) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks. could you please explain why renaming the second "response" did create a closure finally?

Comment: most likely because it´s just a reference and not a copy

Comment: ...but you should really use one api call for this